# Can an Ember data record be created that doesn't fill in unset properties with undefined or null?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, undefined

Let's say this is my ember model:

import DS from 'ember-data'

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  foo: DS.attr('string'),
  bar: DS.attr(undefined),
  fizz: DS.attr('string'),
  buzz: DS.attr('string')
})
```

and this is some data I collect from a form:

```
let data = {
  foo: 'foo_value',
  bar: 'bar_value',
  fizz: 'fizz_value'
}
```

I then pass that data into a `create` call:

```
this.store.create('some_model', data)
```

Inevitably I end up with an Ember data record that has the property `buzz` set, as `undefined`, even though I didn't specify it. Then in mirage, I can see that this becomes the following POST body:

```
{
  foo: 'foo_value',
  bar: 'bar_value',
  fizz: 'fizz_value',
  buzz: undefined
}
```

The problem is that my API doesn't like undefined, empty, or otherwise values it considers "unset."  I have no control over this.

Can I tell Ember not to set those properties on the model, if I haven't passed them in on the `create` call?

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: We use a lightly customized REST serializer, is that the place to handle this?

Comment: We have recently switched to JSONAPISerializer, but as far as I remember, properties not set at all used to be skipped and not transmitted via adapters. I could not find any suitable example, but I guess that [normalizeCreateRecordResponse()](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizeCreateRecordResponse) could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom serializer to form the data in the way that the API is expecting.

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    var json = this._super(...arguments);

    delete json.data.attributes.buzz;

    return json;
  }
});
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/customizing-serializers/